# Edit locally and then upload a file by browser

Tags: php, ajax, file, ftp, edit

I received a strange request from a client:
they want the WebApp I'm developing to be able to open a Excel file (with Excel, not directly in the browser), edit it and then re-save it DIRECTLY upon the FTP...

is that even possible? How could I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Give them a FTP-Account and let them have a folder where they can store their Excel-Files? Or do you mean the data in the files?

Comment: They wanna open the excel file from the browser, edit in Microsoft Excel, and when saving (from Excel) it has to be saved directly in the server----